# How do I get the geometric dual of a mesh?

Tags: mesh

In geometry,a polyhedron is the dual of another polyhedron if you can turn one into another by swapping the vertices and faces. If a vertex has N lines, its replaced by a face with N sides. For example, a cube is the dual of an octahedron. Each vertex has three lines connected to it, so they’re replaced by triangles. The square faces are replaced by vertices with four lines attached.

Is there an operation in blender that lets me select a mesh and get the dual?

Comment: Add the *Geometry Node* modifier, then plug in the Node `Dual Mesh`.

Comment: ... Or.. the add-on _Mesh:Tissue_ includes it in its many features.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's make a short answer from the comments...

The easiest way seems to me (as a big friend of *Geometry Nodes*) to just use the node `Dual Mesh` for this:

[image]

You just need to add a modifier of type *Geometry Nodes* and put the node `Dual Mesh` in between.

The advantage: it remains procedural.

Unfortunately, I could only achieve insufficient/unique results with the addon *Mesh Tissue*, but maybe it's just me.